# Swift String Array Iterating Function

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, func

I am trying input an array with all the months and display them one by one on my scrollable calendar. I am trying to return each individual "month" for each header of the calendar.

I am using the following string array, yet i am unsure how to return a type of "String" for what i desire. Any ideas on what i am doing wrong? Thanks

```
let months: [String] = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

func monthCounter(inputArray:Array<String>) -> String{
    for name in inputArray{
        return name

    }


}
```

I am wanting to call this function to display each "month" string individually.

```
func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, willDisplaySectionHeader header: JTAppleHeaderView, range: (start: Date, end: Date), identifier: String) {


        let headerCell = (header as? MonthsHeader)
        headerCell?.monthsHeader.text = monthCounter(inputArray: months)
    }
}
```

Comment: month counter will return in first go, i.e. January and will come out of loop

Comment: It's wanting me to return a type 'String' after the for loop in my function. How would i do that? Thanks

Comment: I would use this code to get an Array<String> of months which is localized and completed for you: `let months = Calendar.current.monthSymbols`

Comment: ahh, i didn't know that. Thanks a lot ColGraff!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There are serveral problems with your code.
First of all, `Array<String>` should be `[String]` and returning from inside an iteration will terminate the iteration. You can call a function there, or you can `print("\(name)")` for a start to see if your code is working.

As I wrote in my comments below, I think your approach is not correct. Your delegate function does not work that way. Even if a single monthCounter call was able to return multiple times, you would overwrite the same text attribute over and over again. Look for the right delegate function to use that passes in the month for the header that will display. See my comments for a possible hint.

Comment: It is ok to have `Array<String>`. We have `public struct Array<Element> : RandomAccessCollection, MutableCollection`

Comment: You're absolutely right. [String] is just a shorthand version of Array<String>. I thought it was strange, however, using [String] as a type for months and then Array<String> in the function declaration.

Comment: Gotcha, but what should i return after the for loop bracket? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if you are using the right delegate function for what you want to achieve. You need to know which month to return the header text for. You might want to check out `func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, sectionHeaderIdentifierFor range: (start: Date, end: Date), belongingTo month: Int) -> String` where you get a month parameter passed in what you can use directly to determine which month name you need (e.g. just do a `return months[month]`)

Answer (score -2):

```
headerCell?.monthsHeader.text = monthCounter[index of section]
```